# no storyboard uiviewcontroller transparent over other uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

my goal is to present a **transparent uiviewcontroller** on top of another uiviewcontroller so that the background will be a viewcontroller..

```
I'm NOT using storyboard.
```

For now i just added UIViews instead of UIViewcontrollers and everything works well, buy the problem is that i feel that one viewcontroller that manages all of the views (that could be easly in a seperate view controller) considers as bad practice - it just doesnt feel right.

i was thinking about creating a `viewcontroller inside of my base viewcontroller` and then just

```
[self addSubview:otherVC.view]
```

so what i get will be a view controller that has a viewcontroller as a property and presents its view as a subview.

does that consider as a bad practice?

what should i do?

### DOES NOT WORK (works for ipad)

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;  
    [self presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```

tnx.

Comment: in ios6 use addChildViewController

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to make transparent view controller, I made method like this:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot:(CGRect)cropRect {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cropRect.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -cropRect.origin.x, -cropRect.origin.y - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height);
    [self.view.window.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Then I passed it to transparent view controller and made it background view

```
UIImage *bgImage = [self screenshot:self.view.window.frame];
transparentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bgImage];
```

Something like that. I can use another view for this purpose, it's not necessarily has to be self.view